# Android - How to change mount points

Tags: android

Simple question: How to change mount points? My sd-ext is mounting on `\system\sd` but i need it to mount in `\system\sd-ext`
There is no `\etc\fstab` for android, right? So, how to do this?

Comment: Your directory paths definitely don't contain `\` on Android which is a Linux-based OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are interested in `/system/etc/vold.fstab`.

1. ***Backup your system.***
2. Install Root Explorer (I use ES File Explorer).
3. Mount system with write privileges (ES File Explorer has it in Settings).
4. ***Backup*** `/system/etc/vold.fstab` to sdcard and to your PC.
5. Open `/system/etc/vold.fstab` with Text Editor.
6. Here you can find mount points in 3rd column:

   dev_mount sdcard **/mnt/sdcard**
7. Read [something about fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) and comments in file. Be careful. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a device's file structure. You can ask Android where the SD card is with [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). This approach works whether a manufacturer specifies the sdcard is in `/sdcard/`, `/mnt/sdcard/`, or `/way/out/in/the/willy/wacks/sdcard/`.

You should also observe the Android protocol for saving sdcard data in `.../sdcard/Android/data/your.package.name/` with [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) or just [Context.getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: No, i mean, it was mouting in system\sd-ext, and suddenly started to mount in system\sd
Not sure if here is the correct place to ask. It's more to Android cooking/kitchen

Comment: What android will allow you to do easily if you can just find out the procedure, what you can get android to do using a kludge process, and what you can hack android to do with tricks are entirely different questions. You've answered the first  ...but that's not what the OP asked. :-) (Also try not to confuse CAN-NOT with SHOULD-NOT.)